# Symfony 2 Forms - compare two fields

Tags: php, symfony

I have that code in my project:

```
->add('email', 'text', array(
    'translation_domain' => 'KlientRejestracja',
    'label' => 'E-mail (login):',
    'constraints' => array(
        new NotBlank(array('message' => 'emailisNotValid')),
        new Email(array('message' => 'emailisNotValid')),
    )
))
->add('nick', 'text', array(
    'label' => 'Podaj pseudonim<span style="color: red">*</span>:',
    'translation_domain' => 'KlientRejestracja',
    'required'   => false,
    'empty_data' => '',
    'constraints' => array(
        new NotEqualTo(array('value' => '??????','message' => 'imieisNotValid'))
    )               
))
```

How I can compare fields 'email' and 'nick', to check if are not the same?
I tried use NotEqualTo but I don't know what should be compare value.

Comment: Do you use this form with data class?

Comment: yes, I use data class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add callback validator to data class

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;

class xxx
{
...
    /**
     * @Assert\Callback()
     */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
    {
        if ($this->email == $this->nick) {
            $context->buildViolation('error text')
                ->atPath('email')
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
...
}
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html

Comment: As Max said you can use callback or [custom validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html)

Answer (score 1):

A very simple and straigforward approach which does not require callbacks or custom validators would be an assertion making use of the Expression Language. Sounds complicated, but isn’t – see https://pehapkari.cz/blog/2017/02/11/symfony-validator-comparison-constraints/ for an example.

The example is using annotations, but as you wrote above that you use `data_class`, you should be able to do the same in your form type.